# Why do similarly structured vectors not allow a prediction with evalm?

Tags: r, caret

I am trying to use the evalm() function to assess model performance using caret, but I keep getting the following error. Any advice?

```
> evalm(data.frame(preds, test$surg))
***MLeval: Machine Learning Model Evaluation***
Input: data frame of probabilities of observed labels
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]


> dput(test$surg)
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")


> dput(preds)
structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Might help to execute some debugging code.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sometimes knowing which function or parameter was throwing the error will help in understanding what part of the documentation to refer to. The caret system is really an interface to many different methods and packages and we cannot tell which one is involved. It looks like so method's function was expecting a names attribute to be available. Neither of your arguments had a names attribute but that all the inference we can muster in the absence of a [MCVE]. So you are on your own and I was suggesting that you are therefore going to need to rely on your own debugging skills.